# Can you explain these phrases of British accent?

Tags: understanding, accent

Source:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FH2UnMxR3IM

I am unable to understand English commentary in the video between 0:19 and 0:45.

I understood,'Andrew Flintoff ..... 3 wickets in 4 balls ......'.

Dash part is one which I could not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit confusing since there seems to be 3 different commentators (C1, C2, C3), all with slightly different accents.

> C1: Oh he's got him! Freddy Flintoff... THE MAN!
>
> C2: 3 wickets in 4 balls... but the break through, that'll get'em going!
>
> C3: That has got'em going, and it also means a right hander will come in now. Ricky Ponting the skipper coming in at number 3.

BTW, I believe C3 may be Aussie.

Comment: 'The has'  is incorrect?

Comment: How do I understand their accents?

Comment: Hmmm, the only way is through practice and exposure, this is just for the pronounciation, not to mention any idioms which may also exist. In whatever country you are from, you must be able to tell foreigners from native speakers, it's kind of the same with accents (grammar errors aside). Even Brits have problems with other British accents, especially the northern accents. Actually in the video, the "Rick Ponting..." line was very difficult, I had to know that he was skipper of the Aussie side and next up to bat to decipher it.

Answer (score 1):

> Freddie Flintoff... The man! three wickets in four balls... but, the breakthrough... That'll get them going

**The Man!** - an exclamation of approval or congratulation

**but, the breakthrough** - he's created a pivotal moment in the game

**That'll get them going** - it's going to excite the crowd

Hope that helps